# Extending socket.socket with a new attribute

Tags: python, sockets, oop, inheritance, composition

I wish to extend Python `socket.socket` with a new attribute (in particular, a `queue.Queue`, but could be anything else). I am trying
to decide whether I should use inheritance or composition, but at some point both pose a
problem I am not sure how to solve:

A) If I use inheritance, with something like:

```
class MySocket(socket.socket):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        socket.socket.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.queue = queue.Queue()
```

then I have problems when I use operations like

```
connection, client_address = s.accept()
```

because the `accept` method of sockets returns objects of type `socket.socket`, and not of type `MySocket`,
and I am not sure how to convert one into the other. If there is is a trivial OOP way to do this,
I do not know it.

B) The problem before is trivially solved if I used composition instead:

```
class MySocket(socket.socket):
    def __init__(self, true_socket):
        self.true_socket = true_socket
        self.queue = queue.Queue()
```

I would simply implement something like

```
def accept(self, *args, **kwargs):
    con, cli = socket.socket.accept(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return self.__class__(con), cli
```

But then I have another problem. When I need to do

```
readable, writable, exceptional = select.select(inputs, outputs, inputs)
```

`select` works for `socket.socket`. With the A) version I would expect this to work just as is,
but with composition, now that `MySockets` are not instances of `socket.socket`, `select` is broken.

So, what is the best, pythonistic approach for this?

**EDIT**: I forgot to say that the first thing I tried was to add the attribute directly to instances of `socket.socket':

```
s = socket.socket(...)
s.queue = queue.Queue()
```

but I got an exception saying the attribute is unknown for 'socket.socket'.

Comment: Regarding your edit: `socket.socket` uses `__slots__`, which is why you can't add attributes.  This also prevents you from doing something like `s.__class__ = MySocket`... too bad.

Comment: Thanks @augurar, that was my guess. Surely they have a good reason to implement it like that.

Comment: zeycus, did this work for you? I need to do exactly what you're doing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the following, based on `socket.socket.dup()` in [`Lib/socket.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/socket.py#L187):

```
    import _socket

    class MySocket(socket.socket):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(MySocket, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.queue = queue.Queue

        @classmethod
        def copy(cls, sock):
            fd = _socket.dup(sock.fileno())
            copy = cls(sock.family, sock.type, sock.proto, fileno=fd)
            copy.settimeout(sock.gettimeout())
            return copy
```

You can now use the constructor to create new `MySocket`s, or use `MySocket.copy()` to create a `MySocket` from an existing `socket.socket`.  Note that in most cases you should close the original socket after creating the copy.

Comment: Nice, I did not know about `socket.socket.dup()`, I'll try your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `select.select()` explicitly allow you to use your own class as long as you implement `fileno()`:

> You may also define a wrapper class yourself, as long as it has an appropriate fileno() method (that really returns a file descriptor, not just a random integer).

So something like this should work:

```
class MySocket(socket.socket):
    ...
    def fileno(self):
        return self.true_socket.fileno()
```

Alternatively, if you are using Python 3.4+ you can use the [`selectors`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/selectors.html) module which lets you associate `data` (such as the queue itself) with each registered socket, which you can retrieve it with `BaseSelector.get_key()`, e.g. `sel.get_key(true_socket).data` (it is also returned by `BaseSelector.select()`). If you use `selectors.DefaultSelector()` you'll also get the benefits of `kqueue`/`epoll`/etc when those available, without needing to write your own fallback to `select`.

None of the options seem particularly "Pythonic", but `socket.socket` does not appear to be designed to be subclassed, so composition is more likely to be forward-compatible.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you should try inheritance with `super`

```
class NewSocket(socket.socket):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NewSocket, self).__init__()
```

Comment: Thanks @MishaVacic, I understand this is a bit more Pythonistic, but would solve none if my problems, would it?

Comment: @zeycus Could you post somewhere the code,I will try it.

Comment: I can't see how this will work (it was my first thought before I found this page) - things like `accept()` return a `socket.socket`, not a `NewSocket`, so you're out of luck. There's no (sensible) way to "upgrade" a `socket.socket` to a `NewSocket`.